# Merge two sas card into one

Tags: hardware-raid, megaraid, raid-controller

I have one existing raid card (9240-8i)with 8 sas hdd, but i want to add 8 more hdd with another raid card (same model), but i  wan to merge with existing raid and add it as expansion, can it be done?

Comment: If you need expansion, use expanders behind your MegaRAID controller. As simple as that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. GENERALLY not, and no with MegaRaid. There was once one that coudl do that (RaidCore IIRC) but that technology is not available anymore.

As RAid cards function as independent sub-controllers you can not have a Raid volume spanning 2 of them.

You can do that in the OS though.

Comment: Just bear in mind that if you do that, you _can_ end up decreasing your resilience, by increasing dependencies.